# Shiny hover show ONLY variable value

Tags: r, shiny, hover

Here's a reprodcuible example, close to a Shiny App I'm working on:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot1", hover = "plot_hover"),
  verbatimTextOutput("info")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point()
})

output$info <- renderPrint({
nearPoints(mtcars, input$plot_hover, threshold = 10, maxpoints = 1,
           addDist = TRUE)[1]
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here's the app, with the hover functionality shown, the white cross is the mouse pointer:
[image]

I want to show only mpg value, no rowname. I tried this with nearPoints:

```
nearPoints(mtcars, input$plot_hover, threshold = 10, maxpoints = 1,addDist = TRUE)[1,1], which resulted in:
```

[image]

What I want is just the mpg value, no rowname, no [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4ahS.jpg)], nothing. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cat() can be used to do this.

the following code, should do the trick for you

```
  output$info <- renderPrint({
    val <-nearPoints(mtcars, input$plot_hover, threshold = 10, maxpoints = 1,addDist = TRUE)[1,1]

    cat(val)
  })
```